# Difference between 2 dates in days

Tags: ruby

I have 2 dates and difference between them can be over a month. I want to find a difference between them in day. However, `b.days - a.days` turns a blind eye to to the months and, possibly, years too.

```
require 'date'

a = Date.parse("20141030")
b = Date.parse("20141230")

b.day - a.day #=> 0
```

What's the easier way to find such a difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just subtract the one from the other:

```
(b - a)
# => (61/1)
(b - a).to_i
# => 61
```

The reason you got `0` is `b.day` and `a.day` returns day of the month: `30`. (30 - 30 = 0)

```
b.day
# => 30
a.day
# => 30
```

Comment: this works fine. but I'd like to know also how to iterate a date day by day in a pure ruby (not rails)? Just `a.days + 11 gets me only to 30 or 31 and beyond that it gets stuck.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp, Instead of `a.days + 11`, try `a + 11`.  If you want to get day of month: `(a.day + 11).day`